# Finding in regex pattern the name of possible groups

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Let's consider the string `r"(?P<DEF_FUNC>def (?P<NAME_FUNC>\w+)\s*\((.*?)\):)|(?P<OTHERS>\w+)"` which be used later for defining a pattern.

I would like to find in this string the names used for defining the groups from the regex's point of view. Here, this names are `DEF_FUNC`, `NAME_FUNC` and `OTHERS`.

How can I achieve that by taking care of escaping issues ?

Comment: You mean you want to get `DEF_FUNC`, `NAME_FUNC` and `OTHERS`? Okay, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, Iv'e updated and clarified a little my question. I've tried nothing because I am a noob with regexes.

Comment: What does "by taking care of escaping issues" mean?

Comment: @DSM Your answer is great. By escaping, I was just thinking of things like ``r"\?P<DEF_FUNC>def"`` which doesn't contain any group to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find them in the `groupindex` dictionary (see docs [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html#re.regex.groupindex)):

```
>>> import re
>>> rstr = r"(?P<DEF_FUNC>def (?P<NAME_FUNC>\w+)\s*\((.*?)\):)|(?P<OTHERS>\w+)"
>>> regex = re.compile(rstr)   
>>> regex.groupindex
{'DEF_FUNC': 1, 'OTHERS': 4, 'NAME_FUNC': 2}
```

Doing the usual tricks if you want them in value order:

```
>>> sorted(regex.groupindex, key=regex.groupindex.get)
['DEF_FUNC', 'NAME_FUNC', 'OTHERS']
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot ! I really need to find a good book or tutorial for regexes in Python.